# Can we use kafka connect to insert data from topic to Ms sql server db without using confluent platform

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Can we use kafka connect to insert data from topic to Ms sql server db without using confluent platform. We are having licensing issues. Everywhere I am doing RnD, cant find without Confluent. Please help!

Comment: What licensing issues do you have? Both JDBC sink and source connectors do not require any license.

Comment: Confluent has changed the license policy, which will not be useful on future base for our clients. So can't use that.

Comment: If you're not using that connector within a competing product to Confluent Platform, then you're not breaching the terms of the license

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka Connect is part of Apache Kafka, and licensed under Apache 2.0.

If you want to stream data to a database then you have the option of the [Kafka Connect JBDC Sink connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc), which is [Confluent Community Licence licensed](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-community-license-faq).

I'm not aware of another JDBC sink for Kafka Connect.